# How to filter product using tier price in Magent 2.4.x

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, elasticsearch, tierprice, graphql

I am using Magento v2.4.3, Elasticsearch 7.13.1 with Graphql. I want to apply a price filter on tier price value. As price coming as per customer group and default filter getting applied on price attribute.

Is there any way to apply a filter on tier price?